# How to send HTTP POST request from localhost to the nodemailer running on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2

I am new to ReactJS, NodeJS and Linux systems. I am developing React app in which I am creating a contact me form. Once user fills the detials and message, contact form should send me an email on my ID.

I have refered to this link and its working fine on my localhost: https://mailtrap.io/blog/react-contact-form/

Now in order to run my backend part (Express.js + Nodemailer) 24x7, I moved my backend code to the AWS EC2 instance. Using SSH, I run the server and I am listening on port 5000.
[port status on Linux server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqaJL.png)

Here is my code:
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVsdw.png)

Is this right way to send post request from my localhost to my backend server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using a form inside your react code to handle the post request

```
<form action="https://amazon-url/your-post-method" action="post">
    <!-- your inputs here -->
    <input type="submit"value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

make sure to put name property on every input you want to send in your post if you have  inside the form it Will be sent as a property my_name inside the request body. The form will send the post request for you when you click the Submit button.

Another alternative is to use a custom js like you are using in your code method, for this you could use a Library such as Ajax or arios to send your request or the default fetch js api, your code should work just fine

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I was using wrong url to send post request. It should be `"http://${AWS_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP}:5000/contact" ` not `"http://${AWS_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP}:5000"`